# restoring a DB snapshot to a different zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I'd like to restore a snapshot from a DB instance in one region to a DB instance in another region.

I can copy the DB identifier but in the Connectivity section I only have two options for "Virtual private cloud (VPC)" - "Default VPC (vpc-21cbe95b)" and "Create new VPC". The VPC I want, however, that's in a different zone, has a totally different ID - vpc-e681478d.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

The alternative would be to do mysqldump and then import with mysql, which would work, but I figure restoring the snapshot would be waaaaay faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Copy your snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html) to the other region, then you'll be able to create a RDS database in that region.

Quick summary of steps - see the link above or Google it for more details

- Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console at
  https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.
- In the navigation pane, choose Snapshots.
- Select the DB snapshot that you want to copy.
- For Actions, choose Copy snapshot.
- To copy the DB snapshot to a different AWS Region, for Destination
  Region, choose the new AWS Region.
- (See AWS link for other options)
- Choose Copy snapshot.